# Disable Cloud Font from Office 365 (remove it from the font list)

Tags: microsoft-office, fonts, cloud

I have a Microsoft Office 365 subscription and try to disable cloud font in Excel, Powerpoint, Outlook and Word because the font list is far too long when the cloud fonts are included.  I saw a older thread here ([How do I remove or disable downloadable fonts in Microsoft Word and Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/1311744/how-do-i-remove-or-disable-downloadable-fonts-in-microsoft-word-and-excel)) but it doesn't work.  I have unselected the Optional Connected Experiences under Excel Option> Trust Center> Privacy Settings and restarted Office, but the cloud fonts still appear in the font list and I could even continue to download those cloud fonts when I tried to test it.
Is there anyway to disable it and at least remove them from the font list?

Comment: Try in *File > Account > Manage Settings (under Account Privacy)*, to clear the check box "Turn on all connected experiences"  and click OK. See also [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1311748/8672).

Comment: If you have the enterprise version, please also check whether the "DownloadContentDisabled" registry is helpful. `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\common\privacy`, downloadcontentdisabled=2

Comment: Disabling the "connected experiences" seems not to remove Cloud Font (any more) in 07/2023.